# Passing <select> as jQuery event's parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, select, parameters

when I pass a `<select>` element as a parameter to jQuery event (using trigger) the event handler gets only the first `<option>` of that `<select>`. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

I wrote a simple Snippet to demostrate it.
 Please see the output in the console.

```js
var onInputMounted = function(e, data) {
  console.log("mounted", data);
};

var onInputUnmounted = function(e, data) {
  console.log("unmounted", data);
};

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(changes) {
  changes.forEach(function(element, index) {
    var allChangedNodes = [];
    var allChangedInputs = [];

    if (element.type === "childList") {
      // get all changed (added/removed) HTML nodes
      if (element.addedNodes.length > 0) {
        allChangedNodes = Array.prototype.slice
          .call(element.addedNodes)
          .map(function(e, i) {
            return {
              node: e,
              event: "mounted"
            };
          });
      } else if (element.removedNodes.length > 0) {
        allChangedNodes = Array.prototype.slice
          .call(element.removedNodes)
          .map(function(e, i) {
            return {
              node: e,
              event: "unmounted"
            };
          });
      }

      // get all changed (added/removed) HTML :input fields
      allChangedInputs = allChangedNodes
        .map(function(e) {
          return $(e.node)
            .find(":input")
            .addBack(":input")
            .map(function(i, input) {
              return {
                input: input,
                event: e.event
              };
            });
        })
        .reduce(function(arrLike1, arrLike2) {
          var arr1 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arrLike1);
          var arr2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arrLike2);
          return arr1.concat(arr2);
        });
    }

    // trigger the corresponding event: mounted (for added inputs), unmounted (for removed ones)
    for (var i = 0; i < allChangedInputs.length; i++) {
      console.log("trigger", allChangedInputs[i]);
      $("#container").trigger(
        allChangedInputs[i].event,
        allChangedInputs[i].input
      );
    }
  });
});

// register events
$("#container").on("mounted", onInputMounted);
$("#container").on("unmounted", onInputUnmounted);

// observe changes on DOM
observer.observe($("#container")[0], {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  attributes: false,
  characterData: false
});

// append a div with two inputs
$("#container").append(
  '<div><input id="name" /><select id="gender"><option value="male">male</option><option value="female">female</option></select></div>'
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

I trigger the events "mounted" and "unmounted" like this:

```
$("#container").trigger(
   allChangedInputs[i].event,
   allChangedInputs[i].input
);
```

Where `allChangedInputs[i].input` is the HTML input has been added (mounted)/removed (unmounted)

The problem is when this input is a `<select>` the event handler receives it only as `<option>`. Any clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `trigger` method takes either an array or an object, and it is trying to convert `allChangedInputs[i].input` to an array.

Simply converting it to

```
[allChangedInputs[i].input]
```

solves your problem, see **demo** below

```js
var onInputMounted = function(e, data) {
  console.log("mounted", data);
};

var onInputUnmounted = function(e, data) {
  console.log("unmounted", data);
};

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(changes) {
  changes.forEach(function(element, index) {
    var allChangedNodes = [];
    var allChangedInputs = [];

    if (element.type === "childList") {
      // get all changed (added/removed) HTML nodes
      if (element.addedNodes.length > 0) {
        allChangedNodes = Array.prototype.slice
          .call(element.addedNodes)
          .map(function(e, i) {
            return {
              node: e,
              event: "mounted"
            };
          });
      } else if (element.removedNodes.length > 0) {
        allChangedNodes = Array.prototype.slice
          .call(element.removedNodes)
          .map(function(e, i) {
            return {
              node: e,
              event: "unmounted"
            };
          });
      }

      // get all changed (added/removed) HTML :input fields
      allChangedInputs = allChangedNodes
        .map(function(e) {
          return $(e.node)
            .find(":input")
            .addBack(":input")
            .map(function(i, input) {
              return {
                input: input,
                event: e.event
              };
            });
        })
        .reduce(function(arrLike1, arrLike2) {
          var arr1 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arrLike1);
          var arr2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arrLike2);
          return arr1.concat(arr2);
        });
    }

    // trigger the corresponding event: mounted (for added inputs), unmounted (for removed ones)
    for (var i = 0; i < allChangedInputs.length; i++) {
      console.log("trigger", allChangedInputs[i]);
      $("#container").trigger(
        allChangedInputs[i].event,
        [allChangedInputs[i].input] //this line
      );
    }
  });
});

// register events
$("#container").on("mounted", onInputMounted);
$("#container").on("unmounted", onInputUnmounted);

// observe changes on DOM
observer.observe($("#container")[0], {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  attributes: false,
  characterData: false
});

// append a div with two inputs
$("#container").append(
  '<div><input id="name" /><select id="gender"><option value="male">male</option><option value="female">female</option></select></div>'
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Ok this makes sense and therefore I marked the answer to be correct. But I still have a follow up. I did some research and discovered that jQuery uses its makeArray function to build an array from an object. But why does this function return an array of <option>s when I pass an HTML <select> element? On the other hand it returns an array containing the <input> it that was the parameter!?

Comment: @muhanerd Can you point me towards a source that says *jQuery uses its makeArray function to build an array from an object* in case of trigger?

Comment: Also if you do `allChangedInputs[i].input[0]` it shows `option`.

Comment: well I guess I formulated the sentence wrongly. Here what I meant: depending on your statement _it is trying to convert allChangedInputs[i].input to an array_ I thought about the possible methods to do this and tried them:
1) wrapping the parameter in [], or
2) .toArray() but this only works if the parameter was already a jQuery Object, or
3) makeArray() which causes the problem I have.

So I **supposed** (not discovered) that jQuery uses makeArray to convert the parameter into an array. Do you think jQuery does this in a different way?

Comment: @muhanerd I went through the documentation of trigger, there is no mention of makeArray. Also makeArray is only a short hand of `[].slice.call(array-link)`. So, i am assuming something like this would be happening behind the scene.

Comment: I guess I found it : https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event/trigger.js#L69

Comment: @muhanerd In that case, it simply converted a Nodelist to an array in your case.

Comment: still don't get why they didn't simply do: [data] instead of makeArray(data). With [data] I would get [<select>] back but now I get [<option>, <option>] which doesn't make sense for me!

Comment: I guess that is because trigger's data parameter is also suppose to take an object which may not necessarily be a Nodelist